# Drawing UIView vs Drawing CGContext Path

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiview, cgcontext

I would like to know what is more effective to draw a rectangle in a view between using a 
`UIView` :

```
UIView *box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(ax, ay, width, height)];
box.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
box.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
box.layer.borderWidth = lineWidth;
[self.view addSubview:box];
```

or `CGContext` :

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, ax, ay);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, ax+width, ay);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, ax+width, ay+height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, ax, ay+height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, ax, ay);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: The only answer to this question should be measure and see what is most efficient for your exact use-case.

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on what you want to achieve. If you're drawing lots of rectangles you should probably go the `CGContext` way. If it's just a rectangle around some other view elements, you're better of using the UIView method.
Generally speaking I think using UIViews to just draw stuff on the screen is not encouraged , so when in doubt use CGContext